# Изменение функции print()

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как изменить функцию `print()`, чтобы она печатала все в верхнем регистре?

Answer (score 6):

```
def upper_print(f):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        f(*[i.upper() if hasattr(i, 'upper') else i for i in args], **kwargs)
    return wrapper


print = upper_print(print)
```